# URL rewrite in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I am pretty new to Nignx and the LEMP stack and struggling to write clean URLs.

I want to rewrite:
`https://example.com/search/something&1` *to* 

`https://example.com/search.php?query=something&page=1`

How do I proceed to achieve this ?

Comment: PLease check you post. Your target and redirection url both are same

Comment: Do you want this to `https://example.com/search/something&1` to `https://example.com/search.php?query=something&page=1` or opposite

Comment: @SahilGulati Updated my question :)

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt get your question, Do you want this to `https://example.com/search/something&1` to `https://example.com/search.php?query=something&page=1`

Answer (score 1):

`rewrite ^/search/(.*)&(.*)$ /search.php?query=$1&page=$2`

I think you're thinking about it backwards.  You want to rewrite `/search/something&1` => `/search.php?query=something&page=1`

In your code you will generate links that look like `/search/something&1` and then nginx will rewrite them into regular links with url query parameters which PHP can understand.

Comment: It works but all my external resources as in css & js files fail to load.

Comment: @CodeWalker you'll need a separate location block like this location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {} that looks for requests ending in .css or .js and route them normally, do this before your rewrite and you can use break; to make sure no later rules get processed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work you out.

`([A-Za-z]+)` matches all lower case or upper case letters, one or more than one.

`([\d]+)` matches digits one or more than one.

```
rewrite /search/([A-Za-z]+)&([\d]+) /search.php?query=$1&page=$2;
```

This will redirect only those $request_uri which follow these patterns like

```
 /search/something&12
 /search/xxxyAAA&1212
 /search/XXyyZZ&12
```

And does not prevent you css, js execution request to rewrite.